# Integer para String

Tags: c++, string, qt

No QT Creator 5, como faço para converter Integer para string?
No Visual Studio 2012 havia o comando:

```
std::to_string(10);
```

Mas não funciona no QT.
Tentei:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
  std::cout << std::to_string(10);
  return a.exec();
}
```

O erro é esse:

```
G:\PROJETOS\CPP\untitled1\main.cpp:7: error: 'to_string' is not a member of 'std'
   std::cout << std::to_string(10);
                ^
```

Comment: Você quer converter para `std::string` ou `QString`? Coloque o código que está tentando fazer, o problema pode ser outro. E coloque qual o erro ou problema ocorrido.

Comment: Para std::string.

Comment: Dê mais detalhes para eu complementar a resposta. Coloque o código todo. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Por que usar `std::string`, você está tentando modificar um código existente?

Comment: O código que você postou não tem o que você perguntou. E ele não está completo.

Comment: Pronto. É assim que está, não tem mais nada.

Comment: Se você vai escreveu no console e não usa nenhum recurso da Qt, porque está usando `QCoreApplication`? Qual é o compilador que está sendo usado? É MinGW? Qual versão?

Comment: É apenas um exemplo. Preciso usar nessa ocasião.

Comment: Para ativar C++11 no QtCreator adicione `CONFIG += C++11` no arquivo de configuração do projeto (o `.pro`). Isso se o compilador suportar suportar C++11.

Comment: Não sei qual é o objetivo final do código, mas normalmente se vai usar Qt, uma opção comum é usar os tipos disponíveis no QCore, principalmente para ter tranquilidade ao portar pra diversas plataformas e/ou compiladores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acabei de fazer um teste e funcionou:

```
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string s = std::to_string(10);
}
```

Se não funciona provavelmente você está usando um compilador antigo. Aconselho fortemente a atualizá-lo.

Se quiser quebrar um galho temporariamente pode usar uma função própria:

```
#include<sstream>
template <typename T> std::string to_string(T value) {
  //create an output string stream
  std::ostringstream os;
  //throw the value into the string stream
  os << value ;
  //convert the string stream into a string and return
  return os.str() ;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/String/ConverterInt.cpp).

Fonte: [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24008447/221800).

Compile junto com sua aplicação e não terá problemas.

Comment: ótimo exemplo, assim não é necessário o `c++11`

Answer (score 3):

Para usar `std::to_string` é necessário `C++11`

Porém você pode conseguir fazer de outra maneira usando `sstream`

Um exemplo

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << 10;

    std::string minhanovastring = ss.str();
    std::cout << minhanovastring;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Utilize a função própria da classe: `QString::number();`. Mostrado como segue:

```
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QString>

QTextStream out(stdout);

int main(){

    int num = 10;

    QString s = QString::number(num);

    out << s << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

`QString` é melhor na integração com Qt, e possui mais recursos. Também se torna melhor em diferentes codificações. A única desvantagem é que para projetos não Qt, a `std::string` é o padrão.