# ‘itoa’ não é reconhecido

Tags: c++, string, conversão-de-tipo, gcc

Estou tentando compilar o código abaixo com GCC 4.7.4, mas sempre recebo o erro

> error: ‘itoa’ was not declared in this scope

```
#include "otpch.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

#include "iomap.h"
#include "map.h"
#include "tile.h"

#include "creature.h"
#include "player.h"
#include "combat.h"

#include "iomapserialize.h"
#include "items.h"

#include "game.h"
#include "configmanager.h"

[...]

    bool Map::placeCreature(const Position& centerPos, Creature* creature, bool extendedPos /*= false*/, bool forced /*= false*/)
{
    Monster* monster = creature->getMonster();
    if(monster && g_config.getBool(ConfigManager::MONSTER_HAS_LEVEL))
    {
        uint8_t level;
        if(!monster->getMonsterType()->hideLevel)
        {
            if(monster->isSummon())
            {
                std::string value;
                monster->getMaster()->getStorage((std::string)"monster_level", value);

                uint8_t intValue = atoi(value.c_str());
                if(intValue || value == "0")
                    level = intValue;
                else
                    level = 1;
            }
            else
                level = monster->level;

            char buffer [10];
            monster->name = monster->getName() + " [PDL : " + itoa(level, buffer, 10) + "]";
        }
    }
    bool foundTile = false, placeInPz = false;
    Tile* tile = getTile(centerPos);
    if(tile && !extendedPos)
    {
        placeInPz = tile->hasFlag(TILESTATE_PROTECTIONZONE);
        uint32_t flags = FLAG_IGNOREBLOCKITEM;
        if(creature->isAccountManager())
            flags |= FLAG_IGNOREBLOCKCREATURE;

        ReturnValue ret = tile->__queryAdd(0, creature, 1, flags);
        if(forced || ret == RET_NOERROR || ret == RET_PLAYERISNOTINVITED)
            foundTile = true;
    }

    size_t shufflePos = 0;
    PairVector relList;
    if(extendedPos)
    {
        shufflePos = 8;
        relList.push_back(PositionPair(-2, 0));
        relList.push_back(PositionPair(0, -2));
        relList.push_back(PositionPair(0, 2));
        relList.push_back(PositionPair(2, 0));
        std::random_shuffle(relList.begin(), relList.end());
    }

    relList.push_back(PositionPair(-1, -1));
    relList.push_back(PositionPair(-1, 0));
    relList.push_back(PositionPair(-1, 1));
    relList.push_back(PositionPair(0, -1));
    relList.push_back(PositionPair(0, 1));
    relList.push_back(PositionPair(1, -1));
    relList.push_back(PositionPair(1, 0));
    relList.push_back(PositionPair(1, 1));
    std::random_shuffle(relList.begin() + shufflePos, relList.end());

    uint32_t radius = 1;
    Position tryPos;
    for(uint32_t n = 1; n <= radius && !foundTile; ++n)
    {
        for(PairVector::iterator it = relList.begin(); it != relList.end() && !foundTile; ++it)
        {
            int32_t dx = it->first * n, dy = it->second * n;
            tryPos = centerPos;

            tryPos.x = tryPos.x + dx;
            tryPos.y = tryPos.y + dy;
            if(!(tile = getTile(tryPos)) || (placeInPz && !tile->hasFlag(TILESTATE_PROTECTIONZONE)))
                continue;

            if(tile->__queryAdd(0, creature, 1, 0) == RET_NOERROR)
            {
                if(!extendedPos)
                {
                    foundTile = true;
                    break;
                }

                if(isSightClear(centerPos, tryPos, false))
                {
                    foundTile = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(!foundTile)
        return false;

    int32_t index = 0;
    uint32_t flags = 0;

    Item* toItem = NULL;
    if(Cylinder* toCylinder = tile->__queryDestination(index, creature, &toItem, flags))
    {
        toCylinder->__internalAddThing(creature);
        if(Tile* toTile = toCylinder->getTile())
            toTile->qt_node->addCreature(creature);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Tente usar assim: `string(itoa(level, buffer, 10))`

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1):

Vou responder baseado nas informações que você está passando. Não sei se você vai conseguir aplicar já que está tendo dificuldades muito básicas para uso do compilador.

Parece que está usando uma versão nova o suficiente para usar recursos melhores disponíveis na linguagem. Então ao invés de usar o `itoa`, use o [`std::to_string()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string), então substitua

```
itoa(level, buffer, 10)
```

por

```
std::to_string(level)
```

E o `atoi` também pode ser substituído por `std::stoi()` então substitua:

```
atoi(value.c_str());
```

por

```
std::stoi(value)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Typing/Itoa.cpp).

Lembrando que a resposta funciona se as informações passadas estejam corretas. Se conseguir melhorar a informação da pergunta eu posso melhorar a resposta.

Comment: Como posso melhorar minhas informações ?

Comment: Depois das edições eu não sei se você vai conseguir. EU percebi que você está tentando mexer com algo complexo sem ter uma noção de como estas coisas funcionam. Provavelmente irão aparecer diversos outros problema semelhantes e você vai acabar desistindo. Não quero te desestimular mas sem você procurar entender o funcionamento do que está fazendo você não vai conseguir prosseguir. Inicialmente eu achei que você estava fazendo algum exercício simples. Para quem está começando, resolver algo simples é mais fácil, resolver códigos complexos fica inviável. Isto que passei, resolveu?

Comment: Estou compilando deu novamente de falta de libs, e sobre desistir ? estou estudando essa source a quase 1 ano e ja entendo muita coisa, porem sempre aparece essa brincadeira ^^, resumindo eu removo a modificação que fiz mais não desisto ! claro que se eu conseguir resolver seria melhor :D

Comment: error: ‘to_string’ is not a member of ‘std’   /////   /usr/include/boost/exception/to_string.hpp:72:5: note:   ‘boost::to_string’
     to_string( std::pair<T,U> const & x )

Comment: Experimenta compilar com `-std=c++11`. Você percebe que apesar de estar há 1 ano mexendo com isto, está escorregando em coisas bem básicas? Você provavelmente está tentando subir a escada iniciando pelos degraus de cima, isto não costuma funcionar.

Comment: Sim, mas não consegui achar curso em minha cidade então tenho que me vira pela internet :/

Comment: versão do gcc 4.7.4 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.4-2ubuntu1) minha versao e mesmo assim não reconhece :/

Comment: Não, o objetivo do *site* não é este. Você pode começar procurar informações básicas primeiro, comprar livros, ver aulas básicas na internet, para depois ir atrás de coisas sofisticadas. Uma dica, vai vendo tudo o que tem lá: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info Se souber inglês facilita. Programação sem saber inglês, complica. Você falou que a versão era 4.9.1, agora regrediu? Tem coisa errada aí. Eu me baseei no que você tinha informado. Com informação errada fica difícil responder certo. Você consegue atualizá-lo? Seria melhor trabalhar com as versões mais recentes.

Comment: Veja funcionando: http://ideone.com/KZCgkx

Comment: Também é possível usar esta solução http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45043/101

Comment: Como faço para atualiza em linux meu c++ para 11?

Comment: Esta é outra dúvida, abre outra pergunta para isto. Aqui não é um fórum.

Comment: Nenhum funciona, para funcionar preciso atualizar o c++