# Como posso atualizar o C++ para C11 no Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc

Como posso atualizar a versão do C++ para C11?

Detalhes:

- Ubuntu 14.10 32b
- GCC 4.9.1 (Ubuntu 4.9.1-16ubuntu6)

Comment: Qual distribuição do Linux você usa e qual a versão? Quais os problemas você está tendo em fazer a atualização?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.10 32b

esta dando um erro na hora de compilar uma source e me informei que é por causa do c++11 que precisa ser instalado e não estou conseguindo :'( http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55915/error-itoa-was-not-declared-in-this-scope#55915

Comment: Agradeço seria muito util :D estou o dia inteiro atras de resolver esse problema

Comment: Não vejo fundamento para quererem fechar a pergunta, [*"a pergunta não parece sobre programação?.."*](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2493/6454), só porque não há código não é sobre programação? Segundo o [escopo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) essa pergunta se encaixa em *ferramentas comuns entre programadores"*. Sinceramente é algo bastante decepcionante fecharem uma pergunta como esta, que ao meu ver é válida.

Comment: Aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55915/error-itoa-was-not-declared-in-this-scope#comment115089_55928 ele afirma estar usando a versão 4.7, o que não parece ser o caso, ou seja, talvez nem precise atualizar. Ele não consegue ver direito qual é a versão e não consegue usar o comando necessário para rodar o que ele quer. Ele não sabe nem a diferença entre C++ e C, por isto a pergunta está confusa e levando acreditar que ele realmente quer usar C11, quando não é o caso, ele quer C++11. E se está na versão que ele diz aqui, basta usar o `-std=c++11` conforme eu já mostrei para ele.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na sua situação em especifico não há o que ser atualizado. Conforme [este seu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55915/error-itoa-was-not-declared-in-this-scope#comment114993_55915) você utiliza a versão [4.9.1 do GCC](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/utopic/+source/gcc-4.9), que suporta o padrão [**C11**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/standards.html).

Segundo a [GCC Wiki](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/C11Status):

> GCC 4.9 Mudanças: "Suporte a ISO C11 está agora em um nível semelhante ao suporte ISO C99.."

Basicamente você tem que trocar a função `itoa` por [`std::to_string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/).

O problema real está em usar a função [`itoa`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/), ela não é uma função padrão e não funciona no GCC em Linux (*pelo menos no meu caso*). Um [**exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) deste problema pode ser:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (){
  int i;
  char buffer [10];
  printf ("Digite um número: ");
  scanf ("%d", &i);
  itoa (i, buffer, 10);
  printf ("String: %s\n", buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

Quando for compilar, a seguinte mensagem aparecerá:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o exemplo1
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:9:22: error: ‘itoa’ was not declared in this scope
   itoa (i, buffer, 10);
                      ^
$
```

**Nota**: Se o comando acima retornar o erro *to_string’ is not a member of std*, troque `-std=c++11` por [`-std=c++0x`](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/5894415f-be62-4bc0-81c5-3956e82276f3/entry/the_c_0x_standard_has_been_approved_to_ship23?lang=en).

Segundo [este artigo da IBM](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/5894415f-be62-4bc0-81c5-3956e82276f3/entry/atoi_and_itoa_conversions_in_c_11?lang=en), a função [`std::to_string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/) é uma forma conveniente de implementar o que a função `itoa` faz. O mesmo código, porém para C++, pode ser feito assim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    int numero;
    std::cout << "Digite um número: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> numero;
    std::string str = std::to_string(numero);
    std::cout << "String " << str << std::endl;
}
```

---

Se você utiliza o [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) como IDE, e a mensagem *to_string’ is not a member of std* (ou semelhante) aparecer para você, faça o seguinte:

- Clique em `Settings` ➝ `Compiler..`
- Navegue até a aba `Compiler Settings` ➝ `Compiler Flags`
- Marque a opção *Have g++ follow the coming C++0x ISO language standard -std=c++0x*.

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Compile e execute o código novamente. Isso pode não funcionar em situações especificas, mas geralmente isto resolve.

---

### Atualização

No final das contas o problema foi resolvido utilizando a função [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/), que pode ser utilizado da seguinte maneira:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#define LIMITE 10

int main(){
    int numero = 1234567890;
    char str[LIMITE];
    sprintf(str, "%d", numero);
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

Nota: Nem sempre é recomendado o uso de [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/), neste caso em especifico é sabido de antemão o tamanho da variável `numero`, então não há maiores problemas em usa-la, mas em certas  situações onde não é conhecido o tamanho que uma variável pode assumir (seja a leitura de um arquivo ou entrada do usuário), para evitar [**vazamentos**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52555/6454) utilize a função [`snprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/).

Comment: Estou utilizando linux ubuntu 14.10 e comando build.sh  e make e aparece que o std::to_string não é membro do grupo std::!! Como adaptaria isso ou resolveria esse erro em linux ?

Comment: -sh ./autogen.sh && ./configure --enable-server-diag --enable-mysql --enable-root-permission && make -j 2

Comment: @AaronNtoShinobi Você compila usando essa sintaxe? Se possível abra o terminal e digite o comando: `gedit autogen.sh` copie tudo e coloque no http://www.pastebin.com, coloque o link aqui. Faça o mesmo também para o arquivo `configure`: `gedit configure` copie tudo e coloque no http://www.pastebin.com poste o link aqui também.

Comment: autogen.sh : autoreconf -vfi --warnings=none
////////////////////configure : http://pastebin.com/virTgxjF /////////////// build : http://pastebin.com/dMPsuksE

Comment: error: ‘to_string’ is not a member of ‘std’
 /////////// o erro persisti

Comment: @AaronNtoShinobi Bah, esse código que você está tentando compilar, pode ser disponibilizado? tem como você *uppar* ele em algum lugar e postar o link aqui?

Comment: Você tem skype poderia me informar ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22347/discussion-between-aaron-nto-shinobi-and-qmechanic73).